# C++ cin.ignore causing a seg fault?

Tags: c++, arrays, segmentation-fault, cin

```
int client::add_user(item & item_in)
{
    char temp[ASIZE];
    cout << "\n\nEnter the name of your item: ";
    cin.get(temp, 100, '\n');
    cin.ignore(100, '\n');
    get_upper(temp);
    item_in.name = temp;

    cout << "\n\nEnter in effect one: ";
    cin.get(temp, 100, '\n');
    cin.ignore(100, '\n');
    get_upper(temp);
    item_in.effect1 = temp;

    cout << "\n\nEnter in effect two: ";
    cin.get(temp, 100, '\n');
    cin.ignore(100, '\n');
    get_upper(temp);
    item_in.effect2 = temp;

    cout << "\n\nEnter in effect three: ";
    cin.get(temp, 100, '\n');
    cin.ignore(100, '\n');
    get_upper(temp);
    item_in.effect3 = temp;

    cout << "\n\nEnter in effect four: ";
    cin.get(temp, 100, '\n');

    cout << "this";
    cin.ignore(100, '\n');
    cout << "that";

    get_upper(temp);
    item_in.effect4 = temp;
```

...
Understanding that I am sure there is plenty wrong with this code, the problem I am having is that the first four blocks run just fine, but when I compile this code using g++ and run it, "this" displays, followed by a segmentation fault and no "that".  Any ideas?

Comment: What's the definition of `ASIZE`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg const int ASIZE = 30;

Comment: Is any input longer than 29 characters? In that case you overwrite the stack and you might get unexplained errors such as this.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Tried it with inputs over 30 and one char for each input, no matter what (unless I just hit enter) it always seg faults at the same place

Comment: Are you _sure_ it's segfaulting there, rather than happening to segfault somewhere else (after this code) before the system gets around to flushing cout? (try adding cout.flush() after "that").  Better yet, step it through with a debugger, which will show you exactly where it's falling over.

Comment: Regarding the comment from @brepro, you can also run the program in a debugger to find the location of the crash.

Comment: flush worked, so it's in the function calls after that.  Usually at school I just use Visual Studio, but on my laptop I get a MSBUILD error whenever I try to compile something.  Any other good compilers/debuggers?  Thanks all for the help

Comment: The several lines like `item_in.name = temp` are suspicious. What is `item_in.name`? It looks like you are assigning the address of a temporary array to a variable. This is a problem when the function returns and the array goes out of scope.

Comment: @Blastfurnace So the assignment operator for arrays assigns the location of array[0]?

Comment: Yes, you are assigning the array's address to pointer fields in `item_in`. You have a resource management problem. There are easy ways to handle it and some not-so-easy ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on another of your questions, it looks like the parameter `item_in` is a struct with several `char *` fields. There is a serious problem because the array `temp` only exists for the duration of this function. You are assigning the address of a temporary array to pointers in `item_in`. When the function returns, the array goes out of scope and its memory is no longer yours.

You could fix this by allocating memory to the pointers and copying the data but the **best** solution is to use `std::string` from the C++ standard library. It handles resource management and operations like assignment work as you would expect.

Comment: Can't use strings :(.  I ended up up just assigning the value directly into the struct instead of using an intermediary.